# Using multiple instructions inside ternary operator in C

Tags: c, conditional-operator, operator-precedence, comma-operator

I am new to learning C and I would like to know if it is possible to launch more than 1 instruction inside ternary oparator in C - for example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 7;
int max;
int min;
max = (a>b) ? a, b = min :  b, a = min;   
pritnf("%d %d", min, max);
```

I want to sort those numbers and assign them to a variable max or min.
Is it possible to tell the program that if a > b it will save a as maximum and assign b to minimum? Or do I have to do it using If function?
I think the problem is in using the comma, but I dont know what should I use instead.
The message I get is this:

warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
int max = (a>b) ? (a, b = min) :  (b, a = min);

Comment: "Instruction" is a really loaded term to use here, and does not mean what you think it means in this context. It's often interpreted to mean "machine instruction", and those have limited correlation to C code and its various *statements* and *expressions*. A ternary operator is an expression that contains three sub-expressions, as the name implies. Each expression can contain further sub-expressions, with no specific limit to nesting.

Comment: Hint: How do you think that expression parses according to [operator precedence rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)? Note how `,` is dead last in that list.

Comment: The fact that you have that question is reason enough not to use a ternary expression for this task but a simple `if` / `else` which is far more readable for everybody

Comment: `a , b = min` is two expressions separated by the comma operator.  The right side expression assigns the current value of `min` to `b`.  But at this point in your code, `min` remains uninitialized, so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: The use for `?:` is pretty much only certain rare case function-like macros. There are a few rare cases where it might make switch statements more readable. But in some 99.9% of all other use-cases it is wrong and you should use `if`-`else` instead. The same could be said about the comma operator, it has basically no use outside certain function-like macros.

Comment: Basic rule when writing code: [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) `keep it simple stupid`.

Comment: Are you asking out of intellectual curiosity, or as part of a practical problem?  Theoretically, yes, all three operands of the ternary operator can be arbitrarily-complicated subexpressions, with potentially multiple "parts".  But, seriously, if you're trying to do anything at all complicated, everyone who ever has to work with your code later will thank you if you just use a simple, straightforward `if`/`else` statement instead.

Answer (score 3):

You've got your assignment (`=`) and the comma operator (`,`) backward.
But as suggested in the comments this is obscure and unnecessarily difficult to read.
Just write an `if` statement:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 7;
int max;
int min;

if(a>b){
    max=a;
    min=b;
}else{
    max=b;
    min=a;
}
```

It isn't bad practice to use the ternary operator but avoid using it to perform multiple actions like this. Don't treat it as some kind of inline alternative to `if` just because you can.

The advice for the comma operator (`,`) is more generally to avoid it.
It's superfluous, error-prone and can be confused with the comma delimiter in function calls and declarations.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional operator in C is defined the following way

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-OR-expression
    logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

The assignment and the comma operator have lower precedence.

So this statement

```
max = (a>b) ? a, b = min :  b, a = min;
```

is equivalent to the following statement

```
max = ( (a>b) ? a, b = min :  b) , a = min;
```

Thus the variables `max` and `b` are set to the indeterminate value of the variable `min` if `a` is greater than `b` or to the value of the variable `b` otherwise. And then the variable `a` in turn is set to the indeterminate value of `min`.

It seems what you are trying to achieve is the following

```
max = a > b ? min = b, a :  ( min = a, b );
```

Though the code will be more readable if to split this statement into two statements like

```
max = a > b ? a : b;
min = a > b ? b : a;
```

Pay attention to that there is a difference between the definition of the compound operator in C and C++. In C++ the compound operator is defined like

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

that is the third operand can be an assignment expression.

For example in C++ you may write

```
a < b ? max = b : max = a;
```

while in C this statement will look like

```
( a < b ? max = b : max ) = a;
```

and the compiler will issue an error message because the left operand of the assignment is `rvalue` instead of `lvalue`.

Comment: @chqrlie The assignment operator has a higher precedence than the comma operator. So at first mas is assigned by the value of the comma operator and then a is assigned with min.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the **conditional expression** is:

*conditional-expression:*
      *logical-OR-expression*
      *logical-OR-expression* `?` *expression* `:` *conditional-expression*

Therefore, you must use parentheses at least for the third operand because of operator precedence.

Furthermore, your assignments were incorrect.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 7;
    int max;
    int min;
    max = a > b ? min = b, a : (min = a, b);
    printf("%d %d\n", min, max);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `5 7`

To avoid compiler warnings, you could write:

```
    max = a > b ? ((void)(min = b), a) : ((void)(min = a), b);
```

Note however that this method is very unusual, confusing and error prone. Use the ternary operator to perform just one computation at a time:

```
    int max = (a > b) ? a : b;  // max could even be declared as const int max = ...
    int min = (a > b) ? b : a;  // same for min
```

or just use an `if` statement:

```
    if (a > b) {
        max = a;
        min = b;
    } else {
        max = b;
        min = a;
    }
```

C is very versatile... Not every possibility is to be used and abused. Here are some more convoluted ones to avoid:

```
    // recursive
    *(a > (*(a > b ? &min : &max) = b) ? &max : &min) = a;
```

```
    // symmetric
    (min = a) < (max = b) || (max = a) > (min = b);
```

```
    // compact
    (min = max = a) > b ? (min = b) : (max = b);
```

Comment: _Very poetic and useful ;)._

Comment: It may worth noting that one more advantage of the double conditional operator form is that it allows for `min` and `max` to be declared as `const`. The generated assembly is [similar](https://godbolt.org/z/oeTWeTzf1).

Comment: @Bob__: indeed `min` and `max` are initialized, not set so they can be declared `const` but I personally dont `const` qualify local variables. I only but consistently use `const` for pointer targets and global objects.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
(a < b) ? {min = a; max = b;} : {min = b; max = a;}
```

It's not beautiful, but usually you can use an execution scope as an expression argument, works for switch-case, I see no reason why it would not work here.

Comment: *Does this not work?* No it does not, but adding a couple of keywords fixes it: `if (a < b) {min = a; max = b;} else {min = b; max = a;}`

Answer (score 0):

Don't abuse the conditional operator. Doing so only makes code cryptic.

Instead, you can use C's innate values of 1 (true) and 0 (false.)

This code *looks* a bit more complex because it has 3 test cases. Apart from the tiny array `pair`, it is directly translatable to your simpler code.

```
int main() {
    int test[][2] = { { 5, 7 }, { 5, 5 }, { 5, 3 }, };

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof test/sizeof test[0]; i++ ) {

        // two assignments, just like "int a = 5; int b = 7;"
        int pair[2] = { test[i][0], test[i][1] };

        // a conditional (stored for use)
        int max = ( pair[0] < pair[1] );

        // a print statement
        printf( "%d %d\n", pair[!max], pair[max] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
5 7
5 5
3 5
```

Think about reading your code in 6 months or 6 years. "What was I thinking???"